# Enabling Hibernate query logging through Java code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, batch-processing

I want to print a particular hibernate query in UAT environment. However, I do not want to enable hibernate logging for all the queries since it will start generating huge logs.
Is there a way I can enable hibernate query logging through java code just before the query I want to print and then disable it immediately? Please note that I am using Spring data Jpa repository.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logging library that you use.

I think Spring uses SLF4J and logback so something like the following should work:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

and afterwards set

```
loggerContext.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is away to do customized logging with help of logback but not sure it will help to log the particular SQL logs.

Use this link -https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging

Comment: As I have already mentioned in the question, I do not want to do it at the application level. I want to do it programatically only for a specific block of code